# Example with the given conditions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Can someone please give me an example to show that it is possible to show that $X_n$ goes to c in probability,where c is some real number, but $E(X_n) = a_n$ for each n,where $a_n$ is some given sequence of real numbers?

Comment: Did you mean that $a_n\not\to c$? Also, what have you considered so far?

Comment: Yes $a_n$ can be any sequence. I actually tried a lot of things, tried to see if I could achieve it through Convergence in distribution to c (since c is constant), and tried to construct examples of discrete random variables. Although I finally was able to construct another example other than the one posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Assume WLOG that $c=0$ and take $\Omega:=[0,1]$, $X_n:=na_n\chi_{(0,n^{-1})}$.

Comment: Yes. But we assumed c=0 WLOG. Can we do that? I mean, how can we generalize this to a case when c is not equal to 0?

Comment: Yes: consider $X_n-c$ and $a_n+c$.